# Creating files in Cygwin

Tags: file, cygwin

I know this is a basic question, but I just started using Cygwin and I'm having trouble creating new C files and new files in general. I tried `cygstart filename.c` and it kept saying "file not found".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want an empty file `foo.c`, then `touch foo.c`.

Although if you want to edit it in a text editor, you generally don't have to create a new file beforehand. For example, you could just say `emacs foo.c` or `vim foo.c`, even if `foo.c` doesn't exist yet. This is assuming you have the `emacs` or `vim` packages installed in Cygwin, of course.